# Checkbox in Rails 3.1 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and I know a bit of Jquery. I need a checkbox  that when clicked sends  parameter to controller (using Jquery). How can I do this? Can anyone explain me using examples? Thank you all

Comment: What type of parameter do you want to send?  Also, would you want to perform a request as AJAX, or to load a new page?

Comment: Try asking about real things. You would get a lot better answers this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this general question, The best I can give you is this:

```
function foo{
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.HTML",
        type: "POST",
        data: this.value,
        success: function (){...},
    });    
}

$('input[name="foo"]').change(foo);
```